# Angular - template parse errors <component> is not a known element

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to import a component into another component but the imported component doesn't seem to be found.
Here is the error message:

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
'aktenkorrespondenzenTemplate' is not a known element:
1. If 'aktenkorrespondenzenTemplate' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
                            <div class="viewaktenkorrespondenz">
                                [ERROR ->]<aktenkorrespondenzenTemplate #aktenkorrespondenzenTemplate></aktenkorrespondenzenTemplate>
        "): ng:///AppModule/CreateOrEditAkteComponent.html@54:32
```

**main.module.ts**

```
[...]
import { AktenkorrespondenzenTemplateComponent } from '@app/main/shared/aktenkorrespondenzen/aktenkorrespondenzen-template.component';
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        [...]
    ],
    declarations: [
        [...]
        AktenkorrespondenzenTemplateComponent
    ]
})
export class MainModule { }
```

**aktenkorrespondenzen-template.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'aktenkorrespondenzenTemplate',
    templateUrl: './aktenkorrespondenzen-template.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./aktenkorrespondenzen-template.component.less'],
    animations: [appModuleAnimation()],
})

export class AktenkorrespondenzenTemplateComponent extends AppComponentBase implements OnInit {
[...]
}
```

**create-or-edit-akte.component.ts**

```
import { AktenkorrespondenzenTemplateComponent } from '@app/main/shared/aktenkorrespondenzen/aktenkorrespondenzen-template.component';

export class CreateOrEditAkteComponent extends AppComponentBase implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('aktenkorrespondenzenTemplate') aktenkorrespondenzenTemplate: AktenkorrespondenzenTemplateComponent;
}
```

**create-or-edit-akte.component.html**

```
<div class="viewaktenkorrespondenz">
    <aktenkorrespondenzenTemplate #aktenkorrespondenzenTemplate></aktenkorrespondenzenTemplate>
</div>
```

I would be very thankful for possible solutions.

Comment: Is `CreateOrEditAkteComponent` also a part of the `MainModule`?

Comment: Yes, CreateOrEditAkteComponent is also a part of the MainModule. Also, CreateOrEditAkteComponent is imported into KarteiesComponent, which is also a part of the MainModule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please confirm if MainModule is imported in AppModule and then try this

Create `AktenkorrespondenzenModule` and import it in `MainModule` or import it in AppModule directly.

Or try this:

```
[...]
import { AktenkorrespondenzenTemplateComponent } from '@app/main/shared/aktenkorrespondenzen/aktenkorrespondenzen-template.component';
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        [...]
    ],
    declarations: [
        [...]
        AktenkorrespondenzenTemplateComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        [...]
        AktenkorrespondenzenTemplateComponent
    ]
})
export class MainModule { }
```